# Use property prefixes in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties

I have a simple configuration file in Spring MVC (not Boot) which simply looks like this:

```
@Configuration  
class abstract BaseConfig {
  @Bean(name = "DB")
  public DataSource dataSource() {  
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();  
    dataSource.setUsername("Admin");
    ...  
  }
}
```

To use this config file in different projects and reuse the code, I am using property files:

```
@Configuration  
@PropertySource({ "classpath:my.properties" })
class abstract BaseConfig {
  @Bean(name = "${name.db}")
  public DataSource dataSource() {  
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();  
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
    ...  
  }
}
```

Now I want to support multiple data sources (any bean) in a single project. My idea is to use a `BaseConfig` for each data source, i.e., extent a config each time. Is there a why to use prefixes in Spring MVC like this?

```
@Configuration  
@PropertySource({ "classpath:my.properties" })
class abstract BaseConfig<prefix> {
  @Bean(name = "prefix.${name.db}")
  public DataSource dataSource() {  
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();  
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("prefix.jdbc.user"));
    ...  
  }
}
```

Or is there a better solution to switch propery files?